# How to get Version from AndroidManifest.xml in a Library Project?

Tags: android, version, android-manifest, manifest

How to get Version from AndroidManifest.xml in a Library Project?
Because there, I then don't have any activity in it.

Comment: I've linked two duplicates, depending on whether you mean the _app's_ version number or the _library's_ version number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PackageManager m = getPackageManager();
String app_ver = "";
try {
    app_ver = m.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
} 
catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // Exception won't be thrown as the current package name is
    // safe to exist on the system.
    throw new AssertionError();
}
```

Comment: which class "this" should extends? this is a simple manager which is supposed to return the version of the app.

Comment: So, my class now extends ContextWrapper in order to be able to get "getPackagemanager()".
thx for the tip.

Comment: How does this work for a standalone library, which doesn't have any context of its own, but has its own version code in its Android Manifest.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the specific version of the library (and not the app using that library), use:

```
BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
```

Just make sure that you import the BuildConfig for your library (as literally every android library/app has it's own BuildConfig on it's package path). The Android Studio's Gradle Build system indicates that this is always generated as of version 0.7.0 (see [changelog](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)). This persists as a generated class into the hosting app/library.